# Salesforce1 iOS hangs on splash screen

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, customer-community, high-volume-portal

I'm trying to log into SF1 iOS app using a portal user that has been granted access to a community. I've changed the login host to point directly to the community and I can successfully login, authorise the app to access my info, but then it just hangs on the blue Salesforce1 splash screen..

I can log into the web app fine through browser and access chatter and everything else in the community.. Any thoughts?

Are high volume portal users able to login to salesforce1 iOS app directly into community (assuming their profile has been granted access to the community)?

Comment: Im having the same thing, too, but i am administrator but with community enabled with the community bar appearing on the web browser using a pc.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing. I was told by SF that this should be possible, but I've yet to get it sorted for Community Users to use the mobile app. As you mentioned, mobile site access, etc- all works great but the SF1 app simply hangs.